# Date.AddDays not giving the correct answer

Tags: c#, date, time

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Date_Problem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string bDay = Console.ReadLine();
            DateTime convert = DateTime.ParseExact(bDay,"dd-mm-yyyy",CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture);
            convert = convert.AddDays(999);
            string formatted = convert.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy");


            Console.WriteLine(formatted);
        }
    }
}
```

When I input

> 25-02-1995

it should give me

> 20-11-1997

But I get

> 20-02-1997

Can somebody point out my mistake?

EDIT: Apparently "mm" stands for minutes "MM" stands for months.Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: change `mm`  to `MM`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Date format should be `"dd-MM-yyyy"` (notice MM)

*not* "`dd-mm-yyyy`"

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OdYGSO)

Answer (score 2):

`mm` represents minutes that is why when you input 02 for mm it remains same after adding days. `MM` represents the month which you did not use in output.

Try this:

```
string bDay = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime convert = DateTime.ParseExact(bDay,"dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture);
convert = convert.AddDays(999);
string formatted = convert.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

Console.WriteLine(formatted);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace testing
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string bDay = Console.ReadLine();
            DateTime convert = DateTime.ParseExact(bDay, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture);
            convert = convert.AddDays(999);
            string formatted = convert.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");


            Console.WriteLine(formatted);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Here you go.